# Can you do simple geoprocessing in .NET framework? (not mapping applications, not desktop add-ins)

Tags: arcobjects, .net, arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net

So I will be creating a web application in .NET. It's a data entry application where someone will be inputting a bunch of a stuff from a datasheet and we'll suck it into some database tables that are part of an ArcSDE database. Some of this data will be "manufactured" with conditional statements based on what they input into the form, and here is where geoprocessing comes into play. The user will input a piece of information into the form and if it is of a certain value, we will pull spatial data from the database and do some geoprocessing. It'd just be a buffer and an intersect, pretty simple stuff to do using arcpy...but I need to integrate this into .NET somehow. Can you do geoprocessing inside of .NET? Do you have to call out to a python script?

I've read a bunch of stuff on ArcObjects SDK for .NET and then there's also ArcGIS Runtime SDK for .NET and I don't really know what to use. ArcObjects seems to be all about creating add-ins for the ArcGIS Desktop interface which isn't what we're doing at all. ArcGIS Runtime SDK seems to be all about creating web mapping applications which also isn't what we're doing. **I just want to be able to do some geoprocessing in the background, return a value based on the result, and save it to a database table.** This doesn't seem like something impossible to do within .NET (whether I have to call to a python script or not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArcObject is the key here. You can use it in several ways. As you have found, it could be to build an addin to ArcMap (made very easy by Esri), to create an app similar to ArcMap (via ArcGIS Engine) or to integrate functionalities in your own code

The last case is what you are looking for. Have a look at this [example](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#8c8aa138-d473-47be-9e83-47ae1f83f846.htm). You can create a regular .Net project, add reference to Esri's DLL, enable them in your code (i.e. ensure you have the proper license) and start using the ArcObjects. You don't have to have ArcMap open (though you could).

Comment: Is see the example is done as a standalone console application. This project will have a MVC structure; do you know if ArcObjects will work in such an architecture? All the ArcObject-related code would take place in a controller action, so I don't see why it wouldn't, but figured I'd pick your brain about it since you seem to be knowledgeable on the subject. Thanks!

Comment: @Stuff In a webpage? I have no idea... A desktop app following the MVC principle? Sure, no problem!